# Siteforce Namespace Question

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force.com-sites

I'm looking to create a custom login component on a lightning community (Napilli)
I added a out of the box component and configured it such that it's visible on the community. However, when I try to login in I'm unable to do so. I think the problem has to do with the "siteforce" namespace. I'm not sure if this enabled in my org. Anyone know more about the siteforce namespace?

In short, Im trying to fire this event but it fails to execute:

```
$A.get("e.siteforce:registerQueryEventMap").setParams({"qsToEvent" : 
helper.qsToEventMap}).fire();
```

Answer (score 3):

In your component, make sure you add this line

```
<aura:dependency resource="siteforce:registerQueryEventMap" type="EVENT"/>
```